# Generalization of conformal mapping of a metric along the line of yellow CFT book

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, conformal-field-theory

In the book [CFT](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387947853) by Francesco chapter$-5$ while deriving the conformal maps in $2$ dimension i.e. $5.2,5.3$ or simply $z \rightarrow w(z)$. The author's assumed the initial metric to be $$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
After doing the calculation of transformation and proportionality factor of metric we got the desired result of holomorphic mapping.
My question is what generalisation we get when we start from a general metric $$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{pmatrix}f(z,\bar{z}) & g(z,\bar{z}) \\g(z,\bar{z})& h(z,\bar{z})\end{pmatrix}$$
I tried doing the similar calculation as was done for euclidean metric but I end up with a set of equation with variable coeffecient $$ (a-k)\hspace{2pt} g^{00} + b \hspace{2pt} g^{11} + c\hspace{2pt} g^{00}=0$$ $$ d\hspace{2pt} g^{00} + e \hspace{2pt} g^{11} + (f-k)\hspace{2pt} g^{00}=0$$
$$ g\hspace{2pt} g^{00} + (h-k)\hspace{2pt} g^{11} + i\hspace{2pt} g^{00}=0$$
where the variables from $a$ to $i$ and $k$ are functions of $(z,\bar{z})$. The first set being of form $\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}\frac{\partial w}{\partial z}$ and $k$ being the proportionality coefficient associated with conformal transformation of metric. Since this is not a homogenous equation with constant coefficient I can't use the deterimnant of coefficient $=0$ for nontrivial solution.

Can we go further? If this doesn't work does it mean the holomorphic function are conformal mapping for the case of flat space only and not for curved 2d space like following

[image]

Comment: In 2D every metric can be made flat by a combination of diff and Weyl transformations.

Comment: the holomorphicity condition in terms of a general set of coordinates is given by the beltrami equation, eg see Sec.2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.01055 for a pedagogical discussion